# How to get the directory of a file that you do not know

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a command-based class and adding a unload function where it basically deletes the file's require cache, e.g. I have `foo.js` and that has a class that extends off of the class inside of `Command.js`, when I run the unload function for foo.js, it basically forgets foo.js with `delete require.cache[require.resolve("DIR/TO/foo.js")]`, BUT here is the catch, I do not know the directory to `foo.js`. I don't want the user (basically me) to have to write down the file directory to unload like this:

```js
var dir = "./dir/to/foo.js"
var { Command } = require("./../../Essentials/Command.js")
class foo extends Command {
// data...
}

foo.unload(dir)
```

because that wouldn't make sense, I'd prefer the code would run like `foo.unload()` and it would unload the file.

Here's what my class basically is

```js
class Command {
    constructor(client, info) {
          //code
    }

    unload() {
         delete require.cache[require.resolve('dir')]
    }
}
```

Is there a variable or a built in package that can tell me the dir of the file it's in? E.g. If I use the class in Foo.js it tells me the dir to Foo.js.

Comment: What if there's a different file called `foo.js`? Are you talking about  deep recursive directory traversal?

Comment: Are you talking about knowing within the code of a module what the directory is of your module is? Are you looking for `__dirname` or `__filename`? https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

Comment: I just simply need the path to the `foo.js` file that's inside the Node.JS workspace

AND yes- __filename is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to allow the whole path until the file, your safest bet is to use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd).

[`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) returns the location of where the Node.js process has been invoked, that normally would be the root of your directory, so then you will only need to build the path to the file.